# Unable to create layout when position:fixed is used

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I'm planning to create a layout where one of the DIV is fixed using Bootstrap. However, the DIV is creating an undesirable effect.

**JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/cstoq3ec/**

Here's the HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="simple">
        This is just a plain block
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="simple">
        This is just a plain block
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      <div class="fixed">
        hey
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      <p class="scroll">
        This is the scrollable section.
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.scroll {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: grey;
  color: #fff;
}
.simple {
  background-color: grey;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 15px 0;
}
```

Notice how the red color DIV is extended all the way to the right side! I want it to stay within its DIV. How should I proceed?

Comment: When you use `fixed` position, you take the element out of the flow, so it isn't "inside" your container div any more.

Comment: And hence looking for a solution.

Comment: Well if its not it the flow, it *can't* stay in its div. There is no solution. But if you just want to limit width: the container can't limit the width, so you need to limit the width on the div itself i.e. don't use 100% width.

Comment: as I posted in my answer you need javascript. Maybe rewritte the question adding "javscript and jquery" tags and look if anyone could help you with it.

Comment: I'm using Javascript. AngularJS 4 to be more precise and this plugin `Ng2StickyModule`. The `position: fixed` is generated by the plugin. However, the problem and the layout issue is CSS and thus I avoided the JS question. Thanks though. I'll look for an alternative solution.

Comment: What is the purpose of the fixed div if you don't want it fixed? In other words, how is the plugin making it fixed? Maybe if you explain what you are trying to achieve, we might be able to help you find a solution to that issue.

Comment: I want the DIV to be fixed after a bit of scrolling. Hence the plugin which does an excellent job. However, I also want the DIV only within the left side  where the `class="fixed"` is shown. That's where the problem is. I could use a static width but that will kill the responsive bootstrap template.

Comment: You don't need a static width, you can use a percentage (e.g. 50%) or possibly even the col classes.

Comment: I have tried that. Since it is responsive and the plugin generates the width according to the screen-size; it doesn't work. I tried something like `width: calc(570px - 30px) !important;`. Thanks for you time. I'll figure something out.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. that's why you have `position:absolute`.

Once you use `position:fixed` on an element you get it completely out of the HTML flow so it does not matter what their parents are and their size. You used `width:100%`so it's 100% of window width.

Is you wonder why, then, it is affected by parent padding (left and top margin), it is because you haven't set any "left, top, bottom or right value" and modern browsers automatically set the values based on the parent. use your own value to check as you can see here: **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cstoq3ec/2/)**

```
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  color: #fff;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

which, btw, in my opinion you should never rely on as You may have unexpected problems in some browsers. Once you use absolute or fixed position is highly recomend to set at least "top and left values".

If You need the fixed element same width as Your parent I would use javascript / Jquery so you calculate the width of the parent and then use the value to your fixed element.

Comment: I'm actually using sticky javascript plugin that adds the `position: fixed` when the user begins to scroll. And yes, it creates an unexpected behavior during scroll. Thanks though. I'll look for an alternative solution.